# Initialize object not in controller but in own class - is it any pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

Sometimes I have to fill a model before I pass it to a view. I can do it in an action in a controller:

```
public class FormController
{
    public ActionResult Index(int recruitmentId, int employerId)
    {
        EmploymentForm employmentForm = new EmploymentForm();
        employmentForm.StartDate = new DateTime();
        employmentForm.RecruitmentId = recruitmentId;
        employmentForm.EmployerId = employerId;
        // much more properties with some logic (for example connect to database to fill them)

        return View(employmentForm);
    }
}
```

But then the action is very long so I create my own class and I fill the model there:

```
public class EmploymentFormInitializator
{
    private int _recruitmentId;
    private int _employerId;
    public EmploymentFormInitializator(int recruitmentId, int employerId)
    {
        _recruitmentId = recruitmentId;
        _employerId = employerId;
    }

    public EmploymentForm Init()
    {
        EmploymentForm employmentForm = new EmploymentForm();
        employmentForm.StartDate = new DateTime();
        employmentForm.RecruitmentId = _recruitmentId;
        employmentForm.EmployerId = _employerId;
        // much more properties with some logic (for example connect to database to fill them)

        return employmentForm;
    }
}
```

Then my controller is very short:

```
public class FormController
{
    public ActionResult Index(int recruitmentId, int employerId)
    {
        EmploymentFormInitializator employmentFormInitializator = new EmploymentFormInitializator(recruitmentId, employerId);
        EmploymentForm employmentForm = employmentFormInitializator.Init();

        return View(employmentForm);
    }
}
```

**What pattern I use in that case?** Is EmploymentFormInitializator class maybe a factory, builder or maybe it isn't any pattern?

Comment: If it's not controller, how would you like to organize your code?

Comment: [Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx)

Comment: @CodeCaster - I have very often much more properties with some logic.

Comment: You might want to read about the factory pattern. It's not quite the same, but the closest I think...